# Trying to create an email template, Encoding issue

Tags: php, email

I have downloaded the `order.html` template from here:

http://foundation.zurb.com/emails/email-templates.html

And I load the file into a string, using `file_get_contents`:

```
$mailbody = file_get_contents($template);
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance("Email Template Test")
    ->setFrom(array('no-reply@domain.net' => 'Notification Service'))
    ->setTo("email@domain.com")
    ->setBody($mailbody,'text/html');
$mailResult = $swiftmail->send($message);
```

However, when I view it in Outlook 365 or the w10 Mail app, The encoding isnt correct.  There is a line in the file that says:

`<h4>What&apos;s Next?</h4>`

And in the received email I get:

`What&apos;s Next?`

I think the reason is for some reason It is adding the `&amp;` right after the &.  So really in the code it looks like this: `What&amp;apos;s Next?`, which renders it as above.  It's not like that in the file though, so why is this happening?

Comment: research about entity decoding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your email body has its characters already encoded to html entities, and Swift does the same again. Create your body without html entities (What's next), as plain text and let Swift do the encoding, or provide your body as html_entity_decode($mailBody).

Comment: Aaah, is it SWIFT that's doing that?  Is there anyway to turn that off at all?

Answer (score 0):

You've set content type to `text/html`, which is correct, the problem seems related to `Outlook 365` or the `w10 Mail` app not decoding the hmtl entities correctly.

You probably need [html_entity_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php), i.e.:

```
$mailbody = html_entity_decode(file_get_contents($template));
```

Comment: No, it's still producing the same results :(

Comment: I don't know much about `Swift_Message`, I use php mailer and it's works flawlessly https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/tree/master/examples